# How to increase number of channels of a pytorch tensor?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, tensor

I have a pytorch tensor of format `[N, 2, H, W]`, where 2 is the number of channels. However, the model I am using (pretrained resnet18) requires me to have dimensions `[N, 3, H, W]`. How do I increase the number of channels from 2 to 3?

Comment: Well, it depends on what do you want in this third dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Save your 2 channel image as grayscale to disk and then do the following:

```
import torch
from PIL import Image
from torchvision.models import resnet18

from torchvision import transforms

transform = transforms.Compose([            
    transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(
    mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
    std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
)])

img= Image.open('pic.jpg').convert('RGB')
tensor= transform(img)
tensor= torch.unsqueeze(tensor, 0).float().cuda()

resnet_18_model= resnet18(pretrained= True).cuda() # resnet18()
resnet_18_model.eval()
output= resnet_18_model(tensor)

output= torch.argmax(output)
print('Class Number: ', output.item())
```